# php file_put_contents with FILE_APPEND failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, command-line-interface

First off I am running php 5.4.12 cli on Windows XP.

I am running the following code :-

```
file_put_contents(date('Ymd') . '-Success.csv', $successrecord, FILE_APPEND);
```

This code is within a function that is called within a while loop.

The problem I have is that I get the message "PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(20130318-Success.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied" even though the file appears to contain all the data I was expecting!  The file is within the same directory as the php script and is running as a command line script with php -f.

What can I do about this?  Should I use sleep(2); after calling this? What might be causing this issue, since it can clearly write to the file in question.

Thanks
Craig

Comment: It opens, it appends and closes then warns you?  Looks like an ownership issue. And you are not accessing the file concurrently with lock etc... Interesting. Voting up for the question...

Comment: I've just changed the function that calls this and added sleep(1); before calling file_put_contents and it doesn't error.  Wonder what might be causing this.

Comment: Can you please run php as administrator to check it out?

Comment: I have local admin rights and I am writing to a directory in my home folder.  I'll give it a whirl anyway.

Comment: OK that seemed to work, however what I did in order for that to work was to move my stuff to the C: drive and run as administrator.  So I thought I'd revert my script back to not use sleep(1) and run again as me.  It worked this time, I'm now of the opinion that it's a network related issue, since my script directory is on a local network share.  What do we think?

Comment: We thinks :D ... Ok This is not linux and windows ownerships simply suck. So you should take ownership of your working directory with your local admin user or whatever user you are when firing php. In win7 that is easy you right click and select take ownership... But in xp that may go messy. I will google it for you.

Comment: Here is a dry document from microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421

Comment: Again from the chat:  use exec('net use Z: "\\servername\sharename" PASSWORD /user:USERNAME /persistent:no') before it would work
Just use the UNC though (use \\servername\sharename instead of Z:)

Comment: So use UNC form instead of drive letters etc in paths if you do not give the full path windows may attempt to fill in with (wrong) path with a driveletter etc.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have the option to do that, I'll stick with using sleep.  Thanks again.